# Unordered set of pairs, compilation error

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an unordered set of pairs

So far I have :

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> Move;
typedef std::unordered_set<Move> Set;
```

And I will be creating a set of Moves in the future for now I just have:

```
Set* King::possibleMoves() 
{
  Set hello;    <-------- THINK ERROR OCCURS HERE
  return &hello;
}
```

But i keep getting these 3 errors:

```
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/type_traits:770:38: error: 
  implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::hash<std::__1::pair<int, int>
  >'
: public integral_constant<bool, __is_empty(_Tp)> {};
                                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:1951:40: note: 
  in instantiation of template class
  'std::__1::is_empty<std::__1::hash<std::__1::pair<int, int> > >' requested here
                            bool = is_empty<_T2>::value
                                   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:1973:44: note: 
  in instantiation of default argument for '__libcpp_compressed_pair_switch<unsigned
  long, std::__1::hash<std::__1::pair<int, int> >, false, false>' required here
template <class _T1, class _T2, unsigned = __libcpp_compressed_pair_switch<_T1, _T2>::value>
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:2357:15: note: 
  in instantiation of default argument for '__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<unsigned long,
  std::__1::hash<std::__1::pair<int, int> > >' required here
: private __libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<_T1, _T2>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__hash_table:527:55: note: 
  in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::__compressed_pair<unsigned long,
  std::__1::hash<std::__1::pair<int, int> > >' requested here
__compressed_pair<size_type, hasher>              __p2_;
                                                  ^
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/unordered_set:330:13: note: 
  in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::__hash_table<std::__1::pair<int, int>,
  std::__1::hash<std::__1::pair<int, int> >, std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::pair<int, int>
  >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<int, int> > >' requested here
__table __table_;
        ^
King.cpp:9:7: note: in instantiation of template class
  'std::__1::unordered_set<std::__1::pair<int, int>, std::__1::hash<std::__1::pair<int,
  int> >, std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::pair<int, int> >,
  std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<int, int> > >' requested here
 Set hello;
  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:3081:29: note: 
      template is declared here
template <class _Tp> struct hash;
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:1951:55: error: 
  no member named 'value' in 'std::__1::is_empty<std::__1::hash<std::__1::pair<int, int>
  > >'
                            bool = is_empty<_T2>::value
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:1973:44: note: 
  in instantiation of default argument for '__libcpp_compressed_pair_switch<unsigned
  long, std::__1::hash<std::__1::pair<int, int> >, false, false>' required here
template <class _T1, class _T2, unsigned = __libcpp_compressed_pair_switch<_T1, _T2>::value>
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The whole error is here (wouldnt let me paste above)

http://fixee.org/paste/528pvoq/

Comment: What OS and compiler version are you using?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but you are returning a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: MacOS mavericks and gcc.    Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: Was just about to mention that.

Comment: My guess it that there is no hash function defined for your pair. The issue of returning the address of a local variable will of course sting you later on.

Comment: yeah the local variable was my bad but shall implement the hash actually will be creating a class as suggested below

Comment: I've updated your title to be clearer. Referring to the C++ language as "Cpp" is confusing; that abbreviation typically refers to the C preprocessor. I would have just changed "Cpp" to "C++", but that information is already in the tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That error message appears when you have failed to specialise `std::hash` or provide a hasher type for your unordered container (see e.g. [Using C++11 unordered_set in Visual C++ and clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885563/using-c11-unordered-set-in-visual-c-and-clang)).  The XCode error in this case is particularly unfriendly!

C++11 does not provide a hash for pairs (or tuples), even of hashable types.  [This discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/RMLdM6QpzHA) indicates that this was primarily due to a lack of time to get anything better in; however I'm not aware whether there will be anything better in C++14.

Specialising `std::hash<std::pair<int, int>>` is probably not a good idea (and is not permitted by the language; specialising `std` templates is only allowed for user-defined types), so you'll have to provide a hasher:

```
struct MoveHasher {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::pair<int, int> &val) const { ... }
};
typedef std::unordered_set<Move, MoveHasher> Set;
```

See [How do I combine hash values in C++0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590677/how-do-i-combine-hash-values-in-c0x) for how to write the hash function.

Alternatively, you could make `Move` a user-defined class (probably a good idea!) and then specialising `std::hash` will be fine.

Comment: I'd be tempted to write `struct PairHasher` which works for any pair transparently myself (calling `hash<X>` for each half of the pair).  While I was at it, make it `struct TupleHasher` that supports pairs and tuples.